# How can I get into BIOS in my Sony Vaio VPCEH25EN

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, bios, sony-vaio

I have a Sony Vaio, model VPCEH25EN with me. This is the reference [(Sony Vaio VPCEH25EN)](http://www.sony.co.in/product/vpceh25en). It came up with a window 7 pre-installed. I want to install Fedora along with that. For that I have tried to get into the BIOS of my machine.

I did a long press on Assist button on my laptop. However it didn't work.  When I pressed it, it showed

> Windows is loading files

on a black screen and then showed

> Windows is starting

Then it gets into Vaio Care Rescue mode. There I had only three options

> - Start Recovery Wizard
> - Tools
> - Exit

No BIOS option is showing

I think, Windows does not allow me to get into BIOS mode of my machine, since it starts loading windows files whenever I click on Assist button.

How can I get into my BIOS System?

Comment: If I didn't know any better I'd guess this was because your laptop is booting into a uEFI mode instead of BIOS mode. Hence, the options you're seeing aren't consistent with what you're expecting because they're different modes. This is just a guess though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before you press the Power button, press and hold the Assist button and then the power button. Now you get the menu you want.

If this doesn't work, other things you can try:

- Press and hold the <kbd>F2</kbd> key before pressing the power button.
- Press and hold the <kbd>F3</kbd> key before pressing the power button.

Comment: when I press and hold the assist button, system starts. Dont need to click on power button then

Comment: wierd!!! Did u try the F2 before boot? I'd be hitting on all 'F' keys at startup, in that case

Comment: F2 didn't work. However F3 did the magic !!! Thanks. I was searching for this solution over one month. You saved me.

Comment: @programmer_rkt F keys are the most under-utilized keys. Use them when you get a chance ;-)

Comment: Yes that is correct. And if you have some time, can you provide me with some links that clearly explains how do  install ubuntu along with windows ?

Comment: research more on dual boot. there should be a whole lot of links/videos on the same. Hope your issue is resolved

Answer (score 3):

You need to be faster and press <kbd>F2</kbd>, and instead of pushing the key once, you may need to push it a few times in succession before windows starts to load.

You should not have to go through the BIOS, there’s also something like an ad-hoc boot menu you can choose from. Usually the key for this is displayed at boot. I'm not sure on your Sony, but on a lot of computers it’s <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>… If you can’t figure out which key it is, check the manual.

Comment: Can you provide some more details on ad-hoc boot menu ? whether I can use it for installing ubuntu along with windows ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply... the ad-hoc boot menu is just that. By pressing the right key for your computer model, it will pop up a menu that allows you to choose a one-time boot menu without messing with your standard boot settings. So if you just want to boot once from your usb stick or your DVD, simply select the right device from the menu and your computer will try to boot from that device. The menu will show all possible boot devices, including (but not limited to) every hard disk on your system, CD/DVD, network

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. For your variant of VAIO, following steps may help.

1. Completely shut down windows.
2. Then turn it on & tap <kbd>F2</kbd>, before windows loads.
3. That's it.