# How to access Sony Vaio's BIOS?

Tags: windows-7, bios, sony-vaio

I'm trying to access my BIOS so I can turn on virtualization. I'm running Windows 7 on a Sony Vaio PCG-71913L. I have tried every single <kbd>F</kbd>-key and even my <kbd>Assist</kbd> and not one key will bring me to the BIOS. How can I access the BIOS?

Comment: I presume you mean Bios and not NetBios? And virtualization not visualization?

Answer (score 5):

#### How do I enable virtualization on my Sony Vaio?

1. Make sure the computer is turned off.
2. Turn on the computer using the <kbd>ASSIST</kbd> button **not** the
   <kbd>power</kbd> button.
3. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter the Bios.
4. Select the "Advanced" tab in the Bios to enable Virtualization.

Note:

- Sony has disabled hardware virtualization on some laptops by providing these laptops with a Bios that does not have the feature for users to enable or disable hardware virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a post](https://superuser.com/questions/775849/how-can-i-get-into-bios-in-my-sony-vaio-vpceh25en)  that can help you, the model of the VAIO is different, but when I was looking in Google Images I found that both versions have similar design (or even are the same model), so the procedure could be the same.